# Intrepret bytecode with subprocess.call argument

Tags: python, bash

I have a program that take one argument.

I need to call this program in my python script and I need to pass the argument in bytecode format (like \x42\x43).

Directly in bash, I can do like this and it does work:

`./myprogram $'\x42\x43'`

But with subprocess.call it doesn't work:

`subprocess.call(["myprogram", "$'\x42\x43'"])`

Bytes are not intrepreted.

I try to call my program with `/bin/bash` but my program returns a segfault!

Comment: How does it not work? It's hard for people to help without knowing that.

Comment: Just pass Python bytes to `myprogram`: `subprocess.call(["myprogram", b"\x42\x43"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @acw1668

This works well:
`subprocess.call(["myprogram", b"\x42\x43"])`

But if yours bytecodes are in a variable, you need to do this manipulation:

```
# If you're string is unicode type
mystring = mystring.decode('unicode_escape')
# I choose latin1, because some of my bytecode are bigger than 128
mystring = mystring.encode('latin1')
```

And my bytecodes are correctly interpreted:
`subprocess.call(["myprogram", mystring])`

Answer (score 0):

A quick thing to note: `$` is a bash construct. It is the one which evaluates the variable and returns it's value. This does not happen in general when calling one program from another program. So when you invoke `myprogram` it is up to you to provide all the arguments in a form in which `myprogram` understands them.